# How to make required validator or other validator being triggered error in Page_load even if no error?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to make required validator or other validator being triggered error in Page_load even if no error?

after set scroll bar to (0,0) failed and set focus of a link failed, 
i come with an idea to make a requiredvalidator at the top of page, then hope to trigger a error even if there is no error.

the goal is the focus at the top of page rather than the end of page in iframe

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net, Set "overflow" property in the div contains the iframe, like "overflow:auto", the scroll bar is default at the top. I think it's a property issue.